# How do you find the shortest path between a few specific points in a graph and all the others

Tags: graph

We are given a graph, with, let's say 5 nodes and we want to find the shortest path for each of these to a (few) specific nodes among them. Connections:
1 2, 1 5, 2 3, 2 1, 3 1, 4 5, 5 4, 5 1
and we are looking to find the path from 4 to the rest. We are thinking of BFS, but...

Comment: Are you looking for a specific programming solution? Or general recommendations?

Comment: Both would be fine actually

Comment: bfs works. what is the problem?

Comment: Yea it works, it seems that I have messed it up earlier, thanks